# Redirect http requests to https in wildfly 10

Tags: spring, ssl, https, jboss, wildfly-10

This is my standalone-full.xml configuration with ssl configured
**security realm .**

```
      <security-realm name="SslRealm">
            <server-identities>
            <ssl>
            <keystore path="D:\ncm.keystore" alias="ncm" keystore-password="*****" />
            </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
```

**Subsystem**

```
 <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SslRealm"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```

**Socket Binding**

```
   <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
```

How to redirect to https:///localhost:8443/myApp when user hits http://localhost:8080/myApp

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A rewrite rule can be used to redirect users. In the undertow subsystem (standalone.xml or domain.xml) you will need to create a new rewrite filter and then enable the filter in a new fitler-ref:

Create the new rewrite filter in the filters section. In the example below, users will be redirected to `https://myhostname:443/my-app`. %U is a placeholder for the original request URL path; you want to use %U to make the redirect friendly and keep users' original request URL path.

```
<filters>
<rewrite name="http-to-https" redirect="true" target="https://myhostname:8443%U"/>
</filters>
```

Then, enable the filter and configure a predicate in the host section. The predicate is where you configure what the rewrite filter applies to. In the example below, our rewrite filter will only apply to requests going to port 8080.

```
    <server name="default-server">
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            ...
            <filter-ref name="http-to-https" predicate="equals(%p,8080)"/>
```

Here are the JBoss CLI steps for the same configuration changes above:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/rewrite=http-to-https:add(redirect="true",target="https://myhostname:8443%U")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=http-to-https:add(predicate="equals(%p,8080)")
```

Comment: thanks ! . It actually worked . any reference / documentation /source about  it ?

Comment: also I am unable to run on default 443 port .

Comment: No public documentation.  Regarding port, you need to check if 443 port is accessible or not on windows. In linux, you have to be root (have superuser privileges) in order to listen to TCP or UDP ports below 1024. Not sure about windows.

Comment: Original documentation can be found under [Undertow project](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.4.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html). Undertow is a web server running under the hood of the wildfly 10.

Comment: Is this supported in wildfly-8.1 as well ? I am trying it but its not working there.

Comment: Improvement: adding "%q" to target value is better because it adds parameters to redirect ex: target="https://%v:8458%U%q"

Answer (score 2):

As of WildFly 15: admin console -> web -> filters -> add rewrite rule `https://%v%U`

Then add it to every host you wish with the condition `equals(%p,80)`.

No need to create a rule for every host.

https://leponceau.org/programming/2019-02-06-configuring-wildfly-to-redirect-https-to-http.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
<rewrite name="http-to-https" redirect="true" target="https://my.website.com:443/Web/"/>
```

As you can see without `%U`

It redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS