# Install/Configure SSL certificate Wildfly 11 - Windows

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly, keystore

I'm trying to enable SSL on my wildfly 11 application server, i bought an ssl certificate in godaddy and downloaded a zip file with this inside:

```
1. 22c8728db3996008.crt
2. 22c8728db3996008.pem
3. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

I follow this steps to install, with this commands:

```
1. keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks
2. keytool -import -alias root -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file C:\path\to\cert\22c8728db3996008.crt
3. keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file C:\path\to\cert\gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

Then copy the `keystore.jks` file on the standalone/configuration directory

And modify `standalone.xml` file:

```
<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="mypassword" alias="myalias" key-password="mypassword"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```

And

```
<https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SslRealm"/>
```

Then restart the server but booting appears this error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.SslRealm.key-manager: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.SslRealm.key-manager: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0086: The KeyStore can not be found at keystore.jks
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeyManagerService.loadKeyStore(FileKeyManagerService.java:173)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.AbstractKeyManagerService.createKeyManagers(AbstractKeyManagerService.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.AbstractKeyManagerService.start(AbstractKeyManagerService.java:89)
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0086: The KeyStore can not be found at keystore.jks
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeyManagerService.loadKeyStore(FileKeyManagerService.java:169)
    ... 7 more
```

How can i install and use my ssl certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries, I was able to solve it.
First to create a `keystore file (.keystore)`, install `KeyStore Explorer` and follow this [steps](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/6/Configuring/Install_a_CA_signed_SSL_TLS_certificate_with_KeyStore_Explorer).

Second for add the `keytore file` to Wildfly follow this [steps](http://ni3jboss.blogspot.com/).

To redirect all traffic from the server to `HTTPS` do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752067/redirect-http-requests-to-https-in-wildfly-10).

And that's it, the SSL certificate works ok.

Hope this help to someone.