# How to redirect non www URL to www URL in jboss using undertow

Tags: jboss, undertow

How can I redirect non www URL to www URL in `jboss` using `undertow`.

Tried with the command below and it's going for too many redirects.

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/rewrite=nonwww-to-www:add(redirect="true",target="https://www.localhost:8443%U")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=nonwww-to-www:add(predicate="regex(pattern=^https://localhost:8443,value=https://localhost:8443,full-match=false)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the same, this one focuses on HTTP to HTTPS in `JBoss`, but the accepted answer is pretty detailed, maybe it helps you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752373/14076903

I quote:

"A rewrite rule can be used to redirect users. In the undertow subsystem (`standalone.xml` or `domain.xml`) you will need to create a new rewrite filter and then enable the filter in a new `fitler-ref`."

Comment: i have the question of what to use in regex expression of following.
(predicate="regex(pattern=^https://localhost:8443,value=https://localhost:8443,full-match=false)")