# How to force HTTPS on Wildfly 11?

Tags: java, https, wildfly, wildfly-11

I have an application that communicates with a Wildfly 11 server. Right now everything works with HTTP but I want to use only HTTPS. I would like to know

- how to disable http completely and only use https
- how to redirect http to https

Is there a preferred approach between the 2?

What files do I need to change and in what way?

I found similar questions for Wildfly 10: [Forcing HTTPS redirect on Wildfly 10.0 directs to https://localhost:8443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058998/forcing-https-redirect-on-wildfly-10-0-directs-to-https-localhost8443) and [Redirect http requests to https in wildfly 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752067/redirect-http-requests-to-https-in-wildfly-10) but no sources for 11.

Comment: Steps mentioned for Wildfly 10 are application to Wildfly 11 as well. You can follow same steps. There is no change in security subsystem in wildfly 11.